# Adding compression to a NetCDF file using xarray

Tags: netcdf, rasterio, python-3, xarray

I have a raster that I am trying to compress and convert to a `NetCDF` format with compression level = 9 using the `xarray` package. I assume that the compression is added using the encoding parameter as a dict, but I am not quite sure how I understand what to add completely here:

```
 f = directory + "/D_Passaic_F02_NBR_E0001_WGS84_comp"
 t = xarray.open_rasterio(f)
 encode = {'zlib': True, 'complevel': 9}
 t.to_netcdf(output_dir+"/Test2.nc", encoding=encode)
```

I basically get an error: `KeyError: 'zlib'`, but I am not sure what I am suppose to use here. Suggestions?
The data array shows a single band, and an x, and y variable like this:

```
 <xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 9635, x: 14564)>  

        or, in more detail:

 <bound method ImplementsArrayReduce._reduce_method.<locals>.wrapped_func of 
 <xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 9635, x: 14564)>
 [140324140 values with dtype=float32]
 Coordinates:
   * band     (band) int32 1
   * y        (y) float64 41.06 41.06 41.06 41.06 ... 40.74 40.74 40.74 40.74
   * x        (x) float64 -74.45 -74.45 -74.45 -74.45 ... -73.97 -73.97 -73.97
 Attributes:
     transform:                 (3.2670488250568696e-05, 0.0, -74.447024371179...
     crs:                       +init=epsg:4326
     res:                       (3.2670488250568696e-05, 3.2670488250568696e-05)
     is_tiled:                  1
     nodatavals:                (-9999.0,)
     scales:                    (1.0,)
     offsets:                   (0.0,)
     AREA_OR_POINT:             Area
     HISTOGRAM:                 9090|9307|9097|9209|8729|8864|8744|8864|9181|9...
     TIFFTAG_ARTIST:            HEC-RAS
     TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION:  Depth (Max)>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error hints at xarray trying to find a variable called "zlib" in your data. The correct structure for the encoding dict would be something like:

```
encode = {"precipitation": {'zlib': True, ...}}
```

But due to the way the data was loaded this is tricky.

What you have after loading a file using `open_rasterio` is a `DataArray`. A `DataArray` does not have a structure with variables. When writing to NetCDF your data needs to be a `DataSet`.

If you call `to_netcdf` on a `DataArray`, it will automatically generate a `DataSet` with a variable for the data called "`__xarray_dataarray_variable__`". So this will work but the resulting file will be ugly with a name like that...:

```
encode = {"__xarray_dataarray_variable__": {'zlib': True, ...}}  # yuck!
```

When you built a DataSet manually you can specify the variable name. For example if your band contains DEM data, something like this might make sense:

```
dem = t.to_dataset(name="dem")
```

Afterwards you can specify the encoding dict for that and have a reasonable name in the result:

```
encoding = {"dem": {'zlib': True, ...}}
dem.to_netcdf("dem.nc", encoding=encoding)
```

Sadly compression with xarray is very RAM hungry, watch out for your unsaved work before you run it in case your system OOMs.

References:

- https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_rasterio.html
- https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_netcdf.html#xarray.DataArray.to_netcdf
- https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html

Comment: I don't completely understand the variable part. Its a has a single band and looks like this: ` <xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 9635, x: 14564)>` Why wouldn't you apply the compression to the entire file (or all variable)? I assume band/x/y would be the variables, correct?

Comment: I am confused myself. But looking at the xarray code the possible variables would be "band", "x" and "y" here. I found that by looking at ´t.dims´. No idea if the repr output for ´t´ does not list them.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that I am bringing in a `.tif` file as a `Data Array`using `Rasterio`, not a `Data Set`, like this `t = xarray.open_rasterio(f)`. When I  run `t.dims`, it does return `('band', 'y', 'x')` though.

Comment: Oh that makes sense I think. Can you try https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_dataset.html#xarray.DataArray.to_dataset using a reasonable `name` and then use that as variable name for the encoding? My current answer about the band might be wrong, sorry.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it out :)

Comment: I figured it out right before you posted this, but you are absolutely correct. The whole issue was with using the Data Array instead of a Data Set and not naming the variable being compressed correctly. Thanks for your insight on this and the additions to your anyswer. I am sure this will be helpful to others.